# Stuck on testing a method

Tags: java, junit

I am doing some table testing in word, all of the JUnits are done but i am having trouble testing a method - as i am the tester in this project and not the coder i am struggling to understand what is actually correct or not

```
   public GregorianCalendar calcDeparture(String date, String time) {
        String[] calDate = new String[3];
        String[] calTime = new String[2];
        calDate[0] = (date.substring(0, 2)); //Dat
        calDate[1] = date.substring(2, 5); //Month
        calDate[2] = "20" + date.substring(5, 7); //Year
        calTime = time.split(":");

        //Adds the year, month and day and hour and minute from the above splited arrays
        int year = Integer.parseInt(calDate[2]);
        int month = monthToInt(calDate[1]);
        int day = Integer.parseInt(calDate[0]);
        int hour = Integer.parseInt(calTime[0]);
        int minute = Integer.parseInt(calTime[1]);

        GregorianCalendar newDeparture = new GregorianCalendar(year, month, day, hour, minute, 0);
        return newDeparture;
    }
```

This is the method I am testing. If i pass it the values of "01AUG07 "14:40" i get a gregorian calander back but i don't know if the values inside of it are correct so i can't tick the passed or failed box. What i get back in the BlueJ object inspector is a load of really long numbers :D

can i get some help please

thanks

Comment: I get the impression that your actual question is "How do I check what date/time is represented by an instance of GregorianCalendar?"
The javadoc for GregorianCalendar describes this thoroughly.

Comment: Why's the method called calcDeparture? It only parses the date string.

Comment: In fact, this method is not needed at all. And you are testing it...

Answer (score 3):

I suggest to check all the relevant values of the calendar at the same time using a `SimpleDateFormat()` like so:

```
SimpleDateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat ("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");
String s = f.format (calcDeparture(yourDate, yourTime));
assertEquals ("2007-08-01 14:40", s);
```

Now call your method with odd dates (like 31.12.2999, August 45th, February 29th 2001, etc) to see what you get and how you should handle errors.

Comment: @OP: And please inform the original developer about the SimpleDateFormat class and its usage. He/She might offer you a nice share in his/her this month's salary. If not, then you will surely be able to get a beer, at least.

Comment: @OP: You share this test code with the original developer, and its highly likely this method will not exist anymore for you to test.

Answer (score 2):

1. BlueJ? Consider using an IDE, not an educational software
2. The method is terribly written - working with dates using a strictly-formatted String is wrong.
3. `Calendar` (which is the supertype of `GregorianCalendar`) has the `get` method, which you can use like:

   ```
   Calendar calendar = calcDeparture(yourDate, yourTime);
   int day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR);
   int moth = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH); //this is 0 based;
   ```

   and so on

Answer (score 0):

Why can you just not use the standard getters to check the individual fields, along the lines of:

```
Calendar cal = calcDeparture("01AUG07", "14:40");
if (cal.get(Calendar.YEAR) != 2007) { ... }
```